# if_else using each element of a conditional vector individually

Tags: r, if-statement

I am writing an R program that uses user defined functions to create objects to clean/manipulate our raw data. One of the tasks I am asking of the program is to recode (effectively switch) some portion of a variable based on a date and a set of id's.

```
set.seed(14)

date_switch2 <- as.POSIXct("2018-10-30")
maze_switch2 <- c(2,4)

test <-  data.frame(id = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3), rep(3,8), rep(4,5)),
                    date = sort(rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2018-10-29"), as.Date("2018-11-01"),1),
                                    each = 20), decreasing = F),
                    x = sort(x= round(runif(20,0, 10), 2), decreasing = F),
                    ant = sample(c("n", "s"), replace = T, size = 20))
```

Using this example data I would like to recode/switch `ant` on `date == "2018-10-30"` for `id == c(2,4)` such that `n` becomes `s` and `s` becomes `n`. 
The user of the program is asked which if any dates `ant` needs to be switched and if yes, for which `id`. This is done using

```
d <- readline(prompt = "Did antenna orientation change during study (y/n): ")

  if(d == "y"){
    date_switch2 <- readline(prompt = "On what date did antenna orientation change?: ")
    maze_switch2 <- readline(prompt = "which mazes did antennae change orientation?: ")
  }
```

I have tried using `if_else()` but that didn't work as intended because `maze_switch2` contains two elements, thus only working properly half the time.

```
if(d == "y") { 
     test$ant2 <- dplyr::if_else(test$date >= date_switch2 & test$id == maze_switch2 & as.character(test$ant) == "s", "n", 
                                dplyr::if_else(test$date >= date_switch2 & test$id == maze_switch2 & as.character(test$ant)== "n", "s", 
                                               as.character(test$ant)))  

} else {
  test$ant2 <- test$ant
}
```

I suppose I could make each element separate objects. In this example that would double the amount of code for this task and not by dynamic with the user defined function nor scaleable. This solution needs to be dynamic and scaleable. I have no idea what the user will input.

My latest attempt was to loop through `maze_switch2`; but it results in NA's for all records (i.e. all id's) >= the date of interest.

```
if(d == "y") { 
  for(i in maze_switch2) {
  test$ant2 <- dplyr::if_else(test$date >= date_switch2 & test$id == maze_switch[i] & as.character(test$ant) == "s", "n", 
              dplyr::if_else(test$date >= switch & test$id == maze_switch[i] & as.character(test$ant)== "n", "s", 
                                  as.character(test$ant)))  
}
  } else {
  test$ant2 <- test$ant
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you were very close. I had only to make minimal changes to your code to get it to run.

```
test <-  data.frame(id = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3), rep(3,8), rep(4,5)),
                date = sort(rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2018-10-29"), as.Date("2018-11-01"),1),
                                each = 20), decreasing = F),
                x = sort(x= round(runif(20,0, 10), 2), decreasing = F),
                ant = sample(c("n", "s"), replace = T, size = 20))
```

I use `as.Date` instead of `as.POSIXct`

```
d <- "y"
date_switch2 <- as.Date("2018-10-30")
maze_switch2 <- c(2,4)
```

The only changes I did was replacing `==` with `%in%` in many places for two reasons:

1.to test if d is "y" (I can remember exactly why but I think its better to test for character "sameness" using `%in%`. But feel free to correct me...

2.to test for multiple values in `maze_switch2` with `test$id %in% maze_switch2`

```
if(d %in% "y") { 

  test$ant2 <- ifelse(test$date >= date_switch2 & test$id %in% maze_switch2 & as.character(test$ant) %in% "s", "n", 
                      ifelse(test$date >= date_switch2 & test$id %in% maze_switch2 & as.character(test$ant) %in% "n", "s", 
                             as.character(test$ant)))

} else {
  test$ant2 <- test$ant
}
```

Comment: Thank You!!! The reason I use` as.POSIXct` is because my dataset has a date/time variable that I have to work with. Your answer works perfectly! I've been stalled on this for almost a week. I'll be reading more about %in%